# No getting any results from a TextQuery after restarting the node

Tags: ignite

I am able to [run TextQueries on a cache](https://github.com/crawler-commons/url-frontier/blob/ignite/service/src/main/java/crawlercommons/urlfrontier/service/ignite/IgniteService.java#L343) which has the persistence enabled. When I restart the node I can scan the entries but the TextQueries that worked previously do not anymore. Isn't the Lucene index persisted? Does it need rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the text search does not work well with Ignite's native persistence. As you've found, the index is stored in memory. There is no way to rebuild it. You'd have to do something like copy it from a persistent cache to a memory-based one on startup, which is not ideal but would work.

Comment: thanks @stephen-darlington 
I need to rescan the entries anyway when the process starts so I could simply reinsert them, that should cause them to be reindex, right?